# String regex is not working to split words in closed parenthesis

Tags: java, regex, string, split, tokenize

I am working a string regex to split the below string

```
String input = "( Customer.browse == \"Car Loan\" ) AND ( Campaign.period BETWEEN 2400 AND 600 ) "
            + "AND ( Customer.eligibity == TRUE ) AND ( Campaign.campaign_name == \"Browse To Start\") "
            + "AND ( Customer.application_started == \"Car Loan\" ) AND ( Time.currenttime BETWEEN 800 AND 2000 ) "
            + "THEN ( Notification.message == SUPPRESS)";
```

My string tokenizer class is as below

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

    public class StringRegexClass {

        public ArrayList<String> stringTokenizer(String str) {

            ArrayList<String> tokenList = new ArrayList<String>();
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[(\")]|\\w+.\\w+.\\w+|\\w+.\\w+|==");
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
            while (matcher.find()) {
                tokenList.add(matcher.group());
            }
            return (tokenList);
        }
    }
```

And I am getting output as below when I am passing the string to the above class

[image]

I want to split the strings in parenthesis `( Time.currenttime BETWEEN 800 AND 2000 ) and ( Campaign.period BETWEEN 2400 AND 600 )` as below

[image]

I tried different ways none of it worked can you please suggest what changes I need to make to my regex expression to make it work

Comment: `.` has special meaning in a regex, so you need to escape it. I hope you simply forgot to do that, because if you don't know this core, very basic, part of regex, then you need to go study regex a bit more.

Comment: @Andreas i tried that too but it didn't worked i am newbie to regex i am learning and doing now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you capture the quoted string in full.

You need to escape the `.`

You can use the following regex, but be aware that it will silently skip anything it doesn't recognize:

```regex
[()]|"[^"]*"|\w+(?:\.\w+)?|==
```

In Java 4+:

```
public static List<String> stringTokenizer2(String str) {
    List<String> tokenList = new ArrayList<>();
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[()]|\"[^\"]*\"|\\w+(?:\\.\\w+)?|==");
    for (Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str); matcher.find(); )
        tokenList.add(matcher.group());
    return tokenList;
}
```

In Java 9+:

```
public static List<String> stringTokenizer(String str) {
    return Pattern.compile("[()]|\"[^\"]*\"|\\w+(?:\\.\\w+)?|==").matcher(str)
            .results().map(MatchResult::group).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

*Test (Java 8)*

```
String input = "( Customer.browse == \"Car Loan\" ) AND ( Campaign.period BETWEEN 2400 AND 600 ) AND ( Customer.eligibity == TRUE ) AND ( Campaign.campaign_name == \"Browse To Start\") AND ( Customer.application_started == \"Car Loan\" ) AND ( Time.currenttime BETWEEN 800 AND 2000 ) THEN ( Notification.message == SUPPRESS)";
for (String token : stringTokenizer(input))
    System.out.println(token);
```

*Output*

```
(
Customer.browse
==
"Car Loan"
)
AND
(
Campaign.period
BETWEEN
2400
AND
600
)
AND
(
Customer.eligibity
==
TRUE
)
AND
(
Campaign.campaign_name
==
"Browse To Start"
)
AND
(
Customer.application_started
==
"Car Loan"
)
AND
(
Time.currenttime
BETWEEN
800
AND
2000
)
THEN
(
Notification.message
==
SUPPRESS
)
```

Comment: Andreas - In the question, the `"` before and after `"Car Loan"` have captured as separate groups.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Yes. So? Did you read the first line of my answer?

Comment: Yes, you have mentioned, `I would recommend you capture the quoted string in full.`. Is it possible to capture the quotes separately? I have tried to do so but have failed so far. I'm coming from https://stackoverflow.com/a/61382312/10819573

Comment: @Andreas one last ask if i want to handle two different conditions one condition like Customer.browse == "Car Loan" and another condition like Customer.age  > 30 what changes i need to make to regular expression provided by you

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Since OP is new to regex, we should keep this simple, for now, which is why I recommended that change, to keep it simple. Yes, it can be done, but we'd need advanced regex features like *zero-width positive lookbehind* and *zero-width positive lookahead*, and OP doesn't seem ready for those kinds of advanced features yet.

Comment: @Rahul To match other comparison operators, add `|!=|<=?|>=?` to the end.

Comment: @Andreas sorry for getting back to you again one small help after implementing regex suggested by you double quotes are coming along with string "Car Loan" and if you see output i posted in question double quotes are coming as a separate token and i tried adding the regex condition \\w+.\\w+|== in the last but its not working can you please suggest how can i get quotes as a separate token

Comment: @Rahul I gave a hint for how to do that in a [previous comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61403288/string-regex-is-not-working-to-split-words-in-closed-parenthesis/61403543?noredirect=1#comment108624270_61403543). I don't see why you'd need that, but if you truly want it that way, you should try using those regex patterns to do it. As I said, I believe they are too advanced for your current level of regex, so I didn't use them, and I don't intend to at this time.